# excel unique values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've seen many answers to this questions on the internet (and on stackoverflow) something is not working when I try the solution that everyone seems to suggest.

Basically I have a list of values (say in row 24, column C to U), and I'd like to create a (range) formula in row 25, that would give me the distinct values of the values in the range C24:U24.

I used the formula below

```
=INDEX($C$24:$U24,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($B$25:B25,$C$24:$U$24),0))
```

It is not working, it is just returning the 1st item of the list.

Comment: Maybe a question for superuser?

Comment: Are the values in each cell a single character, string, word, or number? Also, do you want each item in the list to be combined into a single string, and do you want a seperator for each distinct element (like comma-seperated)?

Comment: This formula worked for me when it was entered as an array formula and then dragged across Row 25.  It will return "#N/A" if no other unique values remain in Row 24.

Comment: JMax answer below is the right one (see my last comment on how it actually worked). @Tiago, it's a bit borderline, I agree that excel formulas are not programming strictly speaking, you can consider them so. In any case I used the accurate tag excel-formula, and I searched around and found laods of excel question in here... so I concluded that this fits here ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still have to copy-paste the formula in several cells. In your example, `$B$25` would be the first cell (because of this part of the formula: `$B$25:B25`). When you drag this formula down, it will check if the value is already in `$B$25:B26` and so on.

Comment: I'm not dragging the formula, I'm using the range formula using ctrl+shift+enter.. (also my range is actually a row, but this is irrelevant)

Comment: also I tried to do it as a cell by cell formula, and drag it horizontally on all my row range, but it's coming back with #n/a

Comment: could it be that the excel functions changed a bit messing up the results, I tried similar function in http://www.excelforum.com/excel-worksheet-functions/363302-howto-select-distinct-values-from-list.html and another in http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/03/30/how-to-extract-a-unique-list-and-the-duplicates-in-excel-from-one-column/

Comment: You have to validate your first formula as an array formula with ctrl+shift+enter as you  are already doing. But, you have then to drag the formula (horizontaly if needed :)) to get the other values. Am i clearer ?

Comment: now I got it, the trick is you don't select the whole range and ctrl+shif+enter, but you do that for the first cell as if it was a range and then drag it.. that worked, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I know you didn't ask for a VBA function, but in case some readers out there want to know how to do this via VBA, here is the function. It takes a range of cells and creates a string of the unique elements only. You can add a seperator as well (like if you want them comma-seperated).

```vb
Function UniqueList(ByVal cell_range As range, _
                    Optional ByVal seperator As String = "") As String

Dim vArray As Variant
Dim result As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim v As Variant
Dim dictionary As Object
Set dictionary = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

vArray = cell_range.Value

For i = 1 To UBound(vArray, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(vArray, 2)
        If Len(vArray(i, j)) <> 0 Then
            dictionary(vArray(i, j)) = 1
        End If
    Next
Next

For Each v In dictionary
    result = result & (seperator & v)
Next

If Len(result) <> 0 Then
    result = Right$(result, Len(result) - Len(seperator))
End If

UniqueList = result

End Function
```

For those who care: It dumps the cell values into a variant array, then populates a dictionary with each one (except blank cells). Since dictionaries only hold unqiue keys, it weeds out the dupes. Then I loop through the dictionary and create a string with each entry. I clean up the extra seperator at the end so the list is clean.